# polyfit, TypeError: must be str, not float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Code is as follows:

```
m, b = np.polyfit(df['Combined Length'], df['Mean Runtime'], 1)
```

The line produces the error: 'TypeError: must be str, not float'. Why would it want a string? If I input (2,3,4) and (4,6,8) it works fine. It does not work if the two pandas columns are converted to ndarrays either.

The problem occurs with the initial conversion to arrays.

Comment: In what function does the TypeError happen?
Just read the stack trace.

Comment: The first thing `polyfit` does is `np.asarray(X)` and `Y` - that is, convert the 2 inputs to array.  Does `np.asarray(df['Combined Length'])` work?  If not, look into the proper way of extracting an array from a `df` column.

Answer (score 2):

It works with this toy dataframe:

```
In [441]: df = pandas.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4),columns=list('ABCD')
     ...: )
In [442]: df
Out[442]: 
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
In [443]: np.asarray(df['C'])
Out[443]: array([ 2,  6, 10])
In [444]: np.polyfit(df['B'],df['C'],1)
Out[444]: array([ 1.,  1.])
```

How is yours different?

Answer (score 1):

Applying pd.to_numeric to the columns fixed the problem. They were of type object. I am not sure though why the error message asked for 'str not float'.